Could not load compiled classes for build file and Could not get unknown property 'android' for project : firebase_core
I am unable to build project, everytime I try to build the app it's showing an error which says that:

Could not load compiled classes for build file 'C:\Users\Tanmay Nandwana\AppData\Local\Pub\Cache\hosted\pub.dev\firebase_core-2.14.0\android\build.gradle' from cache.
Failed to notify project evaluation listener.
> Could not get unknown property 'android' for project ':firebase_core' of type org.gradle.api.Project.
> Could not get unknown property 'android' for project ':firebase_core' of type org.gradle.api.Project.

the guide says to build with Flutter:2.10.4 and dart version 2.16.2
I tried to build but unable to build it says packages require greater than 2.16.2 and then i switched to 3.1 then it is showing the above error I mentioned.
i have also tried
flutter clean
flutter pub cache clean

publish_to: 'none' # Remove this line if you wish to publish to pub.dev

# The following defines the version and build number for your application.
# A version number is three numbers separated by dots, like 1.2.43
# followed by an optional build number separated by a +.
# Both the version and the builder number may be overridden in flutter
# build by specifying --build-name and --build-number, respectively.
# In Android, build-name is used as versionName while build-number used as versionCode.
# Read more about Android versioning at https://developer.android.com/studio/publish/versioning
# In iOS, build-name is used as CFBundleShortVersionString while build-number used as CFBundleVersion.
# Read more about iOS versioning at
# https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/General/Reference/InfoPlistKeyReference/Articles/CoreFoundationKeys.html
version: 1.0.0+1

environment:
  sdk: ">=2.16.2 <4.0.0"

# Dependencies specify other packages that your package needs in order to work.
# To automatically upgrade your package dependencies to the latest versions
# consider running `flutter pub upgrade --major-versions`. Alternatively,
# dependencies can be manually updated by changing the version numbers below to
# the latest version available on pub.dev. To see which dependencies have newer
# versions available, run `flutter pub outdated`.
dependencies:
  flutter:
    sdk: flutter

  cupertino_icons: ^1.0.2
  firebase_auth: 
  firebase_core:
  geolocator:
  flutter_image_stack: ^0.0.6
  geocoding: ^2.0.5
  flutter_widget_from_html_core: ^0.8.5+3
  carousel_slider: ^4.1.1
  flutter_html: ^3.0.0-alpha.5
  dotted_border:


this is app/build.gradle



flutter {
    source '../..'
}

dependencies {
    // implementation "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib-jdk7:$kotlin_version"
    // implementation platform('com.google.firebase:firebase-bom:30.4.1')
    // // implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-analytics'
    // implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-core:16.0.5'
    // implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-auth:16.0.5'
    // implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-database:16.0.5'
    // implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-storage:16.0.5'
//    implementation platform('com.google.firebase:firebase-bom:32.1.0')
//    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-analytics'
}
apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'
apply plugin: 'com.onesignal.androidsdk.onesignal-gradle-plugin'

